# Override the __str__ of ExceptionGroup to include the exceptions' message

Tags: python, exception

I was trying to use the new API of `ExceptionGroup` (reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-groups)

And it was just great, so for example if I do:

```
raise ExceptionGroup('Some message', [Exception('first'), Exception('second')])
```

The exception error looks like this:

```
+ Exception Group Traceback (most recent call last):
  |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  | ExceptionGroup: Some message (2 sub-exceptions)
  +-+---------------- 1 ----------------
    | Exception: first
    +---------------- 2 ----------------
    | Exception: second
    +------------------------------------
```

But when I try it in try except clause, it seems like the to string of Exception is to show only the ExceptionGroup's message without the messages of the exceptions as well, so for example if I do this:

```py
try:
    raise ExceptionGroup('Some message', [Exception('first'), Exception('second')])
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception:', e)
```

The output would be:

```
Exception: Some message (2 sub-exceptions)
```

So my idea is to have a new class, let's say `class Errors(ExceptionGroup)` that would override the `__str__` to include also the messages of the exception list, but I'm not sure how to do it, is there a reference to this messages exceptions? In the same way they are created in the traceback?

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-groups)? All the subexceptions are available as an attribute, `.exceptions`. Stringify each of them individually and combine them to form the `__str__` for your class. This isn't magic.

Comment: @ShadowRanger but then the traceback would be different, I want both __str__ and the traceback to have the same string pattern, is there a way to retrieve the traceback string?

Comment: Oh, you just want the actual `str` the traceback displays, without displaying it? The `traceback` module's [`traceback.format_exception`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exception) is for stuff like that.